# Whitelisting/blacklisting using BIND

Tags: domain-name-system, security, bind

So I'm researching possible ways of limiting internet access in a school network. Comparing multiple options and concluding which option is the best in a certain environment. So far I have an idea of how to do: Firewall(PFSense), using specific browser (Safe Exam Browser), using ACL's on a router. But my teacher is really hellbent on me using DNS whitelisting/blacklisting as well.

This would be based on a BIND DNS server and probably making use of dnsmasq. Which if I understand correctly just allows me to edit my /etc/hosts file and put all the "annoying" sites in there so that they get translated to a false IP (0.0.0.0).

Now My question here is, how do I whitelist? How do I make a list of sites which I want to be translated by an external DNS and block all the others? Because so far I have not found a clear explanation as to how to do this.

Comment: Make your teacher read that: https://www.afnic.fr/medias/documents/conseilscientifique/SC-consequences-of-DNS-based-Internet-filtering.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that compared to the other methods like IP address based ACL or hostname based transparent HTTP proxy the DNS whitelisting doesn't add anything new and is easy to circumvent by using other recursive name servers, adding name to `hosts` file or using a proxy.

**Dnsmasq** would be easier tool for this, as you can make the whitelisting with two simple lines per domain, shortened from [Dnsmasq Whitelist](http://www.intellamech.com/RaspberryPi-projects/dnsmasq_whitelist.html) by Gary Dalton:

```
# Don't resolve any DNS, Blacklist all
no-resolv

# Whitelist domains to DNS lookup; 
# domain and forwarder NS (line for each pair)
server=/example.com/8.8.8.8
server=/example.com/1.1.1.1
server=/example.net/8.8.8.8
server=/example.net/1.1.1.1

# all other domains to localhost
address=/#/127.0.0.1
```

With **BIND**, the same would be a bit tricky and needs more configuration. You could add recursion, but use an invalid DNS server as a forwarder. Then, add the whitelisted domains as forward zones using real recursive name servers.

This example creates a [view](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/view.html) for clients in `198.51.100.0/24` network and adds whitelisted domains (equivalent for the Dnsmasq configuration above):

```
view "limitedrecursion" {
     // Network of your clients
     match-clients { 198.51.100.0/24; };
     allow-recursion { 198.51.100.0/24; };
     recursion yes;
     forward only;
     // INVALID FORWARDER
     forwarders { 10.10.10.10; };

     // Forward zones for whitelisted domains
     zone "example.com" in { type forward; forwarders {8.8.8.8; 1.1.1.1; }; };
     zone "example.net" in { type forward; forwarders {8.8.8.8; 1.1.1.1; }; };
};
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Also great that you linked those sources, those will come in handy when writing a paper about the subject.